# Could fusion of Deuterium + Helium3 be started using conventional explosives?

Tags: nuclear-pulse-propulsion

In regards to project Orion, using conventional explosives for a radiation free launch and in the range of 0.03 up to 0.35 kilotons.

What is the smallest amount of fissionable material needed to start nuclear fusion of Deuterium + Helium3?

If not able to initiate fusion with conventional explosives i am looking to find out the minimum amount of fissionable material to initiate fusion for a nuclear pulse pellet with the least radioactive fallout possible.

Comment: This isn't on topic for this site, and isn't really a good format anyways. Including more details would be helpful, and you'd want to ask it at http://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Simple test:  Fusion requires 8-figure temperatures to get a reasonable reaction rate.  How do you propose to get 8-figure temperatures from chemical explosives?  You simply don't have the energy density you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of fusionable material isn't a problem: you can initiate fusion inside a tiny pellet containing [milligrams of fusionable material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ignition_Facility#ICF_basics) if you compress it enough. But you need a facility the size of the [National Ignition Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ignition_Facility) to ignite it.
The only place where we have working fusion at a small scale is inside thermonuclear weapons. These use a fission bomb to initiate the fusion reaction. If there were a way to ignite fusion using conventional explosives, I suspect we'd have seen that in bombs by now.

Comment: We have working fusion on the desktop--just at a rate far too slow to be of use for either power production or spaceship propulsion.